# Django Apache Redhat Permission denied, call to fopen() failed

Tags: python, linux, django, apache, mod-wsgi

/var/log/httpd/error_log says,

```
[Tue Nov 22 12:54:51.763863 2016] [mime_magic:error]  AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py', referer: http://ipaddress/Live
[Tue Nov 22 12:54:51.763953 2016] [mime_magic:error]  AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py', referer: http://ipaddress/Live
[Tue Nov 22 12:54:51.771547 2016] [:error]  (13)Permission denied: client ######## mod_wsgi (pid=39821, process='', application='omadi-trafcbi01.intranet.hdr|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py'., referer: http://ipaddress/Live
```

I moved my project out of my home folder to /var/www/ in an attempt to fix the permission issues (to no avail).

here is what I've added to /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf,

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py
WSGIPythonPath /bin/python3/site-packages:/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic
<Directory /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

I also have a /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/000-default file,

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py
    <Directory "/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>
    WSGIDaemonProcess cbTraffic python-path=/var/www/Django_Project:/bin/python3/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup cbTraffic
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py
</VirtualHost>
```

Here is my wsgi.py file,

```
import os
import sys
import site
sys.path.append("/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic")
sys.path.append("/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py")
from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "cbTraffic.settings")
application = get_wsgi_application()
```

This is my first time trying to launch Django on Redhat.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Unrelated, but you don't need ``/bin/python3/site-packages`` in either of the Python module search path options. You shouldn't even need any of the stuff in ``httpd.conf`` at all so long as you fix ``python-path`` of ``WSGIDaemonProcess`` to have correct path of ``/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic``. And you do not need any of the ``sys.path`` stuff in the ``wsgi.py`` file either. Using the ``<Files wsgi.py>`` in ``Directory`` block of default site would make security access more specific but works without.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My initial issue was with Selinux.  I went to /etc/selinux/config and changed the file so that

SELINUX=permissive

before, my file had said

SELINUX=enforcing

This change got rid of the permission error.

From there I had other errors with either being unable to import site, or being unable to import django.core.wsgi.

I went to the Django docs https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/howto/deployment/wsgi/modwsgi/ and added a virtualenv and used mod_wsgi in daemon mode.

The overall problem I was having was with apache using Python 2.  I would get a tiny message telling me that loading mod_wsgi was being skipped,

```
"AH01574: module wsgi_module is already loaded, skipping".
```

It turns out that I had mod_wsgi (version for python 2) installed on the machine.  I removed this and upon running service httpd start I got the error,

```
"httpd: Syntax error on line 379 of /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf: Cannot load /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so into server: /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so: cannot open shared o...file or directory"
```

It turns out that the mod_wsgi was not loading.  Well, I had forgotten to make the mod_wsgi for python 3 with the new virtualenv location.

I used these instructions for getting mod_wsgi to work with Python 3 on Redhat

https://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/wiki/DownloadTheSoftware

```
cd /usr/local/src
sudo wget https://modwsgi.googlecode.com/files/mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz
sudo tar -zxvf mod_wsgi-3.4.tar.gz 
cd mod_wsgi-3.4/
sudo ./configure --with-python=/usr/bin/python3.3
sudo make
sudo make install
mod_wsgi.so is placed in /usr/lib/apache2/modules/
```

But this time I used my path to python3 within my virtualenv.  I was also installing my pip packages with, "

```
pip install -I <name>
```

".  The -I will install the package within your virtual environment (instead of using the global site-packages).

Here is the main part of my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py process-group=example.com


WSGIDaemonProcess example.com python-path=/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic:/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
WSGIProcessGroup example.com


<Directory /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic>
<Files wsgi.py>
Require all granted
</Files>
</Directory>
```

then at the bottom of my /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf file:

```
LoadModule wsgi_module /etc/httpd/modules/mod_wsgi.so
Include /etc/httpd/sites-enabled/000-default
IncludeOptional conf.d/*.conf
```

This loads the mod_wsgi.so file you made.  As you can see, I also had a sites-enabled/000-default file.  Here are those contents below:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py
    <Directory "/var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic">
      Require all granted
    </Directory>


WSGIDaemonProcess cbTraffic python-path=/var/www/Django_Project:/usr/lib/python3.4/site-packages/cbenv/lib/python3.4/site-packages
    WSGIProcessGroup cbTraffic
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/Django_Project/cbtraffic/cbTraffic/cbTraffic/wsgi.py




</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: Do not use anything from the Google Code site related to mod_wsgi. That is old docs which Google will not let you remove. The latest mod_wsgi version is at this time 4.5.7. Much newer that 3.4. Do not use 3.4. Also see more up to date docs as to how to set up Python virtual environments at http://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/virtual-environments.html you should not use ``site-packages`` in ``python-path`` to set up Python virtual environment.

Answer (score 1):

Appache will typically run as the `httpd` user.  I would make sure that this user has at least read permissions on that directory.  You may want to try:

```
chown -R httpd:httpd /var/www/Django_Project/
```

Comment: I was not sure what the group/user was, since chown -R httpd:httpd /var/www/Django_Project/  gave me the error 'invalid user.'  I used find / -name httpd.conf | xargs grep -i "^user" to find the user and 
find / -name httpd.conf | xargs grep -i "^group" to get the group.  The command  chown -R apache:apache /var/www/Django_Project/ was successful, but I am still getting the same permissions problem.

Comment: What are the permissions on /var/www?

Comment: I changed /etc/selinux/config so SELINUX=permissive and ran

/sys/fs/selinux/envorce via "echo 0 > /sys/fs/selinux/enforce"

This made the previous error disappear!  I am now getting the error "No module named django.core.wsgi" where the error occurs in my wsgi.py file on line "from django.core.wsgi import get_wsgi_application"