# Deploy Django app on Apache server on CentOS 7

Tags: django, apache, ssl, centos7, mod-wsgi

I am following [this article](https://computingforgeeks.com/deploy-python-3-django-application-on-centos-with-apache-and-mod-wsgi/) to deploy a Django app on Apache in CentOS 7.

I have some differences compared to that article:

1 - I used port 443 for `https` (my machine already has port 443 open with `my_app_dns`)

2 - My virtual host config file  `/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf` is as following:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerAdmin xxx@xxx.com
        ServerName my_app_dns
        DocumentRoot /home/centos/path_to_my_app

        Alias /static /home/centos/path_to_my_app/static
        <Directory /home/centos/path_to_my_app/static>
                Require all granted
        </Directory>

        #ErrorLog /logs/apis_error.log
        #CustomLog /logs/apis_access.log combined

        WSGIPassAuthorization On
        WSGIDaemonProcess my_app python-path=/home/centos/path_to_my_app:/home/centos/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_app-8BiokhAz/lib/python3.9/site-packages
        WSGIProcessGroup my_app
        WSGIScriptAlias / /home/centos/path_to_my_app/wsgi.py

        <Directory /home/centos/path_to_my_app>
                <Files wsgi.py>
                        Require all granted
                </Files>
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

3 - My app uses Postgres database instead of SQlite3.

The `DocumentRoot` is set to `/var/www` in `/etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf`. I have also set up self-signed SSL certificate with the file `etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`). Below is some of the content of the `ssl.conf` file:

```
Listen 443 https
...
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
DocumentRoot "/var/www"
ServerName my_app_dns:443
...
SSLEngine on
SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
...
</VirtualHost>
```

With the above setup, when I go to `https://my_app_dns`, I see the sample Apache Test page.

If I change `<VirtualHost *:80>` to `<VirtualHost *:443>` in the file `/etc/httpd/conf.d/django.conf`, going to `https://my_app_dns` yields this error:

```
my_app_dns sends an invalid response
ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

In folder `/etc/httpd/conf.d/`, I have two files : `ssl.conf` and `django.conf`. Both of these define virtual hosts. It seems only the config in `ssl.conf` takes effect and not the file `django.conf`).

I followed [this article](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-create-an-ssl-certificate-on-apache-for-centos-7) for the SSL setup.

What am I missing in this setup sequence in order to deploy the Django app content instead of the Apache Test page?

**Update**:

Following @Lingyan Meng's comment, I transfer the `django.conf` virtual host info to the `ssl.conf` virtual host and delete `django.conf`. After restarting my webpage, I see this error on the browser:

```
Internal Server Error
The server encountered an internal error or misconfiguration and was unable to complete your request.

Please contact the server administrator at root@localhost to inform them of the time this error occurred, and the actions you performed just before this error.

More information about this error may be available in the server error log.
```

So I checked a few log files for clues. In this log file, `/var/log/httpd/ssl_error_log`, I see the following error:

```
[Wed Oct 13 22:37:05.642226 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 2526] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Oct 13 22:37:05.697737 2021] [ssl:warn] [pid 2526] AH01906: RSA server certificate is a CA certificate (BasicConstraints: CA == TRUE !?)
[Wed Oct 13 22:37:11.890802 2021] [mime_magic:error] [pid 2531] [client xxx.x.xxx.xx:62352] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/centos/path_to_my_app/my_app/wsgi.py'
[Wed Oct 13 22:37:11.891123 2021] [mime_magic:error] [pid 2531] [client xxx.x.xxx.xx:62352] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/centos/path_to_my_app/my_app/wsgi.py'
[Wed Oct 13 22:37:11.899659 2021] [:error] [pid 2527] (13)Permission denied: [remote xx.x.xx.xx:116] mod_wsgi (pid=2527, process='my_app', application='my_app_dns|'): Call to fopen() failed for '/home/centos/path_to_my_app/my_app/wsgi.py'.
[Wed Oct 13 22:37:12.185359 2021] [mime_magic:error] [pid 2532] [client xx.x.xx.xx:51889] AH01512: mod_mime_magic: can't read `/home/centos/path_to_my_app/my_app/wsgi.py', referer: https://my_app_dns/
```

I found a thread with a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749906/django-apache-redhat-permission-denied-call-to-fopen-failed). The suggested solution was to change the ownership of `my_app` folder. So I did this:

```
sudo chown -R apache:apache ~/path_to_myapp
```

Then, I verify it with:

```
ls -l ~/path_to_my_app
```

which shows:

```
drwxrwxr-x. 2 apache apache  89 Oct  8 21:33 my_app
-rwxrwxr-x. 1 apache apache 661 Oct  7 19:57 manage.py
drwxrwxr-x. 3 apache apache  19 Oct  8 21:59 static
```

So, server `apache` now owns the folder. But when I restart the server, I still see the same error message in `ssl_error_log` file.

Also, below is the full content of my `/etc/httpd/conf.d/ssl.conf`

```
Listen 443 https
SSLPassPhraseDialog exec:/usr/libexec/httpd-ssl-pass-dialog
SSLSessionCache         shmcb:/run/httpd/sslcache(512000)
SSLSessionCacheTimeout  300
SSLRandomSeed startup file:/dev/urandom  256
SSLRandomSeed connect builtin

SSLCryptoDevice builtin

<VirtualHost _default_:443>
    DocumentRoot "/home/centos/path_to_my_app"        
    ServerName my_app_dns
    
    ErrorLog logs/ssl_error_log
    TransferLog logs/ssl_access_log
    LogLevel warn

    SSLEngine on

    SSLCertificateFile /etc/ssl/certs/apache-selfsigned.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/apache-selfsigned.key
    
    
     <Files ~ "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php3?)$">
           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
     </Files>

     <Directory "/var/www/cgi-bin">
           SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
     </Directory>

     Alias /static /home/centos/path_to_my_app/static
     <Directory /home/centos/path_to_my_app/static>
            Options FollowSymLinks
            Order allow,deny
            Allow from all
            Require all granted
     </Directory>

     WSGIPassAuthorization On
     WSGIDaemonProcess my_app python-path=/home/centos/path_to_my_app:/home/centos/.local/share/virtualenvs/my_app-8BiokhAz/lib/python3.9/site-packages
     WSGIProcessGroup my_app
     WSGIScriptAlias / /home/centos/path_to_my_app/my_app/wsgi.py

     <Directory /home/centos/path_to_my_app/my_app>
            <Files wsgi.py>
                   Require all granted
            </Files>
     </Directory>

BrowserMatch "MSIE [2-5]" \
         nokeepalive ssl-unclean-shutdown \
         downgrade-1.0 force-response-1.0

CustomLog logs/ssl_request_log \
          "%t %h %{SSL_PROTOCOL}x %{SSL_CIPHER}x \"%r\" %b"

</VirtualHost>


SSLCipherSuite EECDH+AESGCM:EDH+AESGCM:AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH
SSLProtocol All -SSLv2 -SSLv3
SSLHonorCipherOrder On

Header always set Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=63072000; includeSubdomains"
Header always set X-Frame-Options DENY
Header always set X-Content-Type-Options nosniff

SSLCompression off
SSLUseStapling off
SSLStaplingCache "shmcb:logs/stapling-cache(150000)"
```

If someone could advise what is going on?

Answer (score 1):

You may remove the django.conf, and move your settings in VirualHost in django.conf into ssl.conf and try again.

Comment: Thanks. I did that. Now I am facing new error messages. I am going to update my question to reflect more info.